# XPath Wildcard -- Any Node Name, Must have Specific Attribute Value

Tags: xpath

I am having difficulty figuring out an XPath query that would allow me to return nodes based on the value of the Program attribute in the example below. For example, I would like to be able to search all nodes for a value of the Program attribute = "011.pas". I tried `/Items/*[Program="012.pas"]` and also `/Items/Item*[Program="01.pas"]` but neither works. What is the correct expression?

```
<Items>
 <Item0 Program="01.pas"></Item0>
 <Item1 Program="011.pas"></Item1>
</Items>
```

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is selected with `@Program`, the child elements of the `Items` element with `/Items/*`, so you want `/Items/*[@Program = '011.pas']`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
/items/*[@Program='011.pas']
```